# Immediately use state value using useState() React Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it possible, to use state value immediately, for example:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const onChange = (value = 42) => {
  setCounter(value); //value === 42
  props.onChange(counter); // counter === 0
}
```

Without using new variable, like

```
const onChange = (value = 42) => {
  const val = value;
  setCounter(val); //val === 42
  props.onChange(val); 
}
```

Comment: Thinking, the correct way to use changed and actual state variable is to use useEffect hook:
`useEffect(()=>{
props.onChange(counter)
})`

Comment: `useEffect(()=>{ props.onChange(counter) }, [counter])` is what you need

Comment: not really a duplicate. the question is "is it possible to use state value immediately?" and the linked "duplicate" doesn't directly answer that question.